# CSS Grid - Design not equal heights on certain divs

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid but I am struggling to make the layout fit.

As you can see below, all is correct, however I want 'Item 1" and "Item 6" to be the same height so it all runs fluidly.

```css
 .grid > div {background:red;border:2px solid blue;}
 .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 10px;
  }
  .span-col-4{grid-column: span 4 / auto;}
  .span-row-2{grid-row: span 2 / auto;}
  .span-row-4{grid-row: span 4 / auto;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="span-row-2">Item 1</div>
  <div class="span-row-4">Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div class="span-row-4">Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div class="span-row-2">Item 6</div>
  <div class="span-row-2">Item 7</div>
  <div class="span-col-4">Item 8</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider more rows and define a the height of rows to make sure they stay equal:

```css
.grid>div {
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows:1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.span-col-4 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.span-row-2 { grid-row: span 2;}
.span-row-3 { grid-row: span 3;}
.span-row-4 { grid-row: span 4;}
.span-row-5 { grid-row: span 5;}
.span-row-6 { grid-row: span 6;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="span-row-3">Item 1</div>
  <div class="span-row-6">Item 2</div>
  <div class="span-row-2">Item 3</div>
  <div class="span-row-6">Item 4</div>
  <div class="span-row-2">Item 5</div>
  <div class="span-row-3">Item 6</div>
  <div class="span-row-2">Item 7</div>
  <div class="span-col-4 span-row-2">Item 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani, is it atall possible to keep the heights fluid? E.g. If I am to add loads of text in 'Item 1' this then makes 'Item 6' box go tiny in height

Comment: Thats exactly it! Thanks alot Temani. Could I confirm what you updated? Thanks!

Comment: @Brad I added `grid-auto-rows:1fr;` to make sure all the rows stay the same

Answer (score 1):

You can apply min-height css

```
.span-row-2 {
    grid-row: span 2 / auto;
    min-height: 46px;
}
```

'Item 1" and "Item 6" height will be the same but make sure wherever you apply span-row-2 the height will be applied. Better use different class name.

Comment: This then breaks the equal height of item 3, item 5, and item 7

Comment: No, it isn't 3 and 5 does not have class only it will be applied into 7 but as I suggest you to use the different class to avoid the issue.